# Como descargar un ZIP desde una clase en android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

Estoy desarrollando una app y necesito descargar un archivo `.zip` que esta alojado en un servidor.

He intentado por GET descargar el archivo pero no he podido, me podrían ayudar con algún método o librería para poder descargarlo?.

La URL de la que intento descargar obedece a algo así: http://servidor.com/archivos/archivo.zip.

Gracias.

Comment: Agrega tu código por favor seguramente tienes, es importante agregues más detalles, revisa [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Según entiendo lo que preguntas, te recomendaría que lo descargaras desde un `WebView` de la siguiente manera:

```
public class WebViewDescarga extends AppCompatActivity {

WebView webView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_webViewDescarga);

    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
    webView.loadUrl(String.valueOf("http://servidor.com/archivos/archivo.zip"));

    webView.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {

        @Override

        public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent,
                                    String contentDisposition, String mimeType,
                                    long contentLength) {

            DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(
                    Uri.parse(url));

            request.setMimeType(mimeType);

            String cookies = CookieManager.getInstance().getCookie(url);

            request.addRequestHeader("cookie", cookies);

            request.addRequestHeader("User-Agent", userAgent);

            request.setDescription("Downloading file...");

            request.setTitle(URLUtil.guessFileName(url, contentDisposition,
                    mimeType));

            request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();

            request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
            //La carpeta de destino seria descargas del telefono
            request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(
                    Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, URLUtil.guessFileName(
                            url, contentDisposition, mimeType));
            DownloadManager dm = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
            dm.enqueue(request);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Downloading File",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Comment: Creo que esto es lo menos recomendable, ¿Porque lo recomiendas de esta forma usando un WebView?

Comment: Porque fue la única manera que funcionó en mi proyecto. Traté de hacer la conexión por `URL` y no me funcionó.